# c# - Why is my child process pipe closing automatically?

Tags: c#, pipe, named-pipes, process.start, namedpipeserverstream

I'm trying to pass information from a child process, that is a pipe, to its parent process that is just a form at this point. I have gotten my named pipes to work between each other when they are independent and not child processes however when I try to use the pipeServer as a child process, it(the child pipeserver process ) starts and then is closed and I can't figure out why. It is also not producing any output even though I have it redirected to my debug.

My pipe server should close after receiving 3 messages from the pipeClient. Currently, it seems to start as it is called and then closes a couple of seconds later automatically when it should be waiting to receive a message from the pipe client.

Any and all help/direction is appreciated.

here is my code:

**From the form calling the process**

```
private void pipeB_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\Mac\Home\Desktop\myPathName\TestNamedPipeB\TestNamedPipeB\bin\Debug\TestNamedPipeB.exe";
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // needed somehow
                //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                process.Start(); // this is where it is starting and closing.

                process.WaitForExit();

                StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput; 
                string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine("s: " + s);

                string output = reader.ReadToEnd(); // used

                pipeConversation.Append(output);
                Debug.WriteLine("pipeConversation: " + pipeConversation.ToString());

            }
        }
```

**my server pipe code**

```
namespace TestNamedPipeB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(100, 15);

            StartServer();
        }
        static void StartServer()
        {
            
            var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("test-pipe");

            if (server.IsConnected == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Currently waiting for a client to connect...");
            }

            server.WaitForConnection();
            
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);

            Console.Write("A client has connected, awaiting greeting from client... \n");

            string emptyArgsString = "PipeA sent an empty message. PipeB (this program) is assuming pipeA has no arugments and is closing";

            int readerCounter = 0;
            int readerMaxInt = 3; // edit me to an int greather than 1 if you want to test

            while (readerCounter < readerMaxInt) 
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(emptyArgsString);
                    Debug.WriteLine(emptyArgsString);
                    MessageBox.Show(emptyArgsString, "M3dida", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    break;
                }
                
                Console.WriteLine("PipeA said: " + line);
                Debug.WriteLine("PipeA said: " + line);
                readerCounter++;
                if (readerMaxInt > 1)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine()); //<-- needed to send a response back if sending multiple messages
                    writer.Flush(); // onus changes to other pipe
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably the worst bug I've ever come across and is so incredibly dirty that it gives a rusty nail a run for its money. I'm also not a formally trained programmer so there's that to take into the equation.

this line: `Console.SetWindowSize(100, 15);` was causing the bug. Once I removed it from the child process, everything worked again. I have no idea why.